# Is it possible to catch die messages that happen inside another perl module?

Tags: perl, lwp, die, xml-simple

I have a SOAP client written in Perl using `LWP` package for the HTTPS transport and `XML::Simple` for the parsing of the XML payloads. From time to time the call to `XMLin` fails with a die() and then my script dies and has to be restarted by a monitoring program that I have written to detect this. This is really not desirable, and so I was wondering if Perl has any facility like the C++ exception handling mechanism where I can catch the die message, ignore it report the error and let my script continue just as if an error occurred? I have read a number of Perl books and looked for this but I have not managed to find something. This is killing my application but I dont want to write my own XML parsing code unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Use a high-level SOAP library such as [SOAP::Lite](http://p3rl.org/SOAP::Lite) that comes with its own error handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; the basic mechanism for doing this would be an `eval`:

```
sub a { die "BAD"; }
eval { a(); }
print "Survived an exception $@";
```

However, there are reasons why you should use more high-level constructs (which are nevertheless constructed on top of this), like [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.11/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) et al. (see the links at the bottom of its documentation).

Answer (score -2):

You can catch the "die" but you can't stop your script from dying by catching it: *When a "__DIE__" hook routine returns, the exception processing continues as it would have in the absence of the hook, unless the hook routine itself exits via a "goto", a loop exit, or a "die()".*

You can run the routines which are susceptible to call the die() inside an eval{} block, though.

Comment: So essentially then my script will terminate whenever the package encounters a condition that calls die() ?? There is nothing I can do at all? Oh well looks like I better start the C++ version....

Comment: well yes, except for that eval of which you have been told twice now